# Create a UIViewController for my class source, how to?

Tags: c#, iphone, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, uitableview

I have this class to create the date source. How do I create a `UIViewController` using this class?

```
public partial class JogosSource : UITableViewSource {

    List<TableItem> tableItems; 
    string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";

    public JogosSource (List<TableItem> items)
    {
    }

    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
    }

    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly want? A view controller that only contains a tableview?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not pretty sure I understand your question.

`UITableViewSource` is a class that combines `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` into one convenient class that contains the methods of both.

So, if you want to use that class, `JogoSource` in your case, as written in MT doc you need to

> Assign an instance of this object to the UITableView.Source property.

To create a `UITableView` element you could follow three different ways:

- Subclass an `UITableViewController` (this class has a table view its own)
- Subclass a `UIViewController` with its own XIB, drag the table within the main view and link it with an outlet
- Subclass a `UIViewController` (with its own XIB, this is optionally), create the table by code

Setting the `Source` for your table view instance could be done in `ViewDidLoad` method. Here you are sure that outlets, for example, are set up correctly.

```
this.YourTable = new JogoSource(yourItems);
```

*Simple advice*

Usually, when you deal with a `UITableViewSource` class you could also inject within its constructor the controller that "controls" that source. This could be useful for example in situations when you deal with `UINavigationController`.

So, I would change the ctr of `JogoSource` as

```
public JogosSource (UIViewController injectedController, List<TableItem> items)
{
    // _controller is a private var of type UIViewController
    _controller = injectedController;
}
```

If your controller is inserted, for example, in a `UINavigationController` and you need to show some details when you select a row, by means of `_controller` you access the parent (an instance of `UINavigationController`).

P.S. There are other possibilities to create a table but I listed the main ones. Furthermore, check the code since I've written by hand.

Hope that helps.